# What is .ncftp?

Tags: ftp

I have a folder in my root called .ncftp, anyone know what that is? I am a complete newbie to SSH and the whole Shell thing. I have just been using FTP.

Comment: or try asking on superuser (so they can tell you to `man ncftp` :)

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, many programs use folders/files in the users home directory to store their configuration. They usually start with a dot, which declares them "hidden". So the `.ncftp` directory you ask for stores configuration stuff for the ftp client you were using. This may also include some command history, last visited hosts, and the like -- all for your convenience.

Lately (at least with Ubuntu) it seems, though, that many applications moved their configuration files to the `.config/` subdirectory to make that more obvious -- and to keep the home directory itself from being cluttered.

Answer (score 0):

**NcFTP - Browser program for the File Transfer Protocol**

The purpose of ncftp is to provide a powerful  interface to the Internet File Transfer.
NcFTP is an FTP client program as the first alternative FTP client. It was created as an alternative to the standard UNIX ftp program, and offers a number of additional features and greater ease of use.
More Info on this at:

- [NCFTP](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftp.html)
- [Wikipedia as always](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NcFTP)

Comment: However the .ncftp folder is not the program itself, but merely the user configuration for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you type `man ncftp`, you'll see there is a section called "FILES" which tells you what files are stored in that directory.